# Can't display SOQL result in a visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have controller, that query some data:

```
public with sharing class SomeController {
    public List<Account> Records {get; set;}
    
    public List<Account> Accslist() {
        Records =[select id from Account];
                
        system.debug(Records);
        return Records;
    }
}
```

And visualforce page that should display all that data.

```
<apex:page  Controller="SomeController" >

<apex:pageBlock title="My Content">
  <apex:repeat value="{!Records}" var="Record" >
    <apex:outputField value="{!Record.Id}"/>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

But it don't prints it. Please, could someone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `Accslist` hasn't been called, so `Records` is still `null` (not empty) since it has been never initialized.
If you need that list as soon as possible you could initialize it in the constructor:

```java
public with sharing class SomeController {
    public List<Account> Records {get; set;}
    
    public SomeController() {
        Records = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
                
        System.debug(Records);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks a lot